# CMake's find_package ignores the PATHS option when building for iOS

Tags: ios, cmake, cross-compiling

Library "foo" depends on library "bar". Both libraries' build system is based on CMake. Library "bar" provides a CMake package that downstream projects, such as library "foo", can use.

"foo" integrates "bar" via Git submodule. "foo" expects that "bar" is built and installed in the submodule path in a specific location. This is how the folder structure looks like:

```
/path/to/foo
+-- bar                  <-- "bar" Git submodule
|   +-- build            <-- "bar" out-of-source build folder
|       +-- install      <-- "bar" installation folder
+-- build                <-- "foo" out-of-source build folder
+-- CMakeLists.txt
```

Here's a minimalistic CMakeLists.txt for "foo" that shows the `find_package` call I'm using:

```
project ( foo )
set ( BAR_INSTALLATION_PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bar/build/install" )
find_package (
  bar
  0.1
  EXACT
  QUIET
  PATHS ${BAR_INSTALLATION_PREFIX}
)
```

This works fine, i.e. `find_package` finds "bar", as long as I build "foo" for the host platform macOS. When I try to cross-compile "foo" for iOS, however, `find_package` fails to find "bar".

I used `-DCMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE=ON` to diagnose the problem, and it appears that `find_package` is simply ignoring the folder that is specified for the `PATHS` option. This is the minimalistic command line that I have arrived at during diagnosis that still exhibits the problem:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=iOS -DCMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE=ON
```

And here's the relevant part of the output that I'm seeing:

```
  [...]
  Paths specified by the find_package PATHS option.
    /Users/patrick/dev/foo/bar/build/install

  find_package considered the following locations for the Config module:

    /Applications/Xcode-11.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/barConfig.cmake
    /Applications/Xcode-11.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/bar-config.cmake
    /Applications/Xcode-11.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/barConfig.cmake
    /Applications/Xcode-11.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/bar-config.cmake
    /Applications/Xcode-11.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/barConfig.cmake
    /Applications/Xcode-11.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/usr/bar-config.cmake
    /Applications/Xcode-11.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/barConfig.cmake
    /Applications/Xcode-11.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/bar-config.cmake
    /Applications/Xcode-11.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/barConfig.cmake
    /Applications/Xcode-11.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/bar-config.cmake

  The file was not found.
  [...]
```

As can be seen `find_package` initially recognizes the `PATHS` option value, but then it ignores the folder when it actually performs the package search in the file system.

How can I tell `find_package` to not ignore the folder specified to the `PATHS` option when cross-compiling for iOS?

Environment: macOS 10.14.6, Xcode 11.2.1, CMake 3.19.2 (installed via Homebrew).

Answer (score 3):

For iOS and Android, CMake sets the `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE` CMake variable to `ONLY` by default. That is, all the `PATHS` that you set are only resolved within `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH`.

If you want `find_package()` to resolve the paths also as host paths, you have to manually set `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE` either to `NEVER` or `BOTH`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Had the same problem on Android, setting `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE` and `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY` to `BOTH` saved my life :)

Comment: Also, there are `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_BOTH` and `NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` options to set such behavior for each call separately.

Comment: I tried to make it work in the past for a GStreamer or OpenSSL framework, but without success. Your suggestion fixed it and instead some workarounds (`target_link_options`/`target_include_directories`) I can just use `target_link_libraries`

Answer (score 1):

I currently have added this to my CMakeLists.txt, between where I'm setting `BAR_INSTALLATION_PREFIX` and where I'm invoking `find_package`:

```
if (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} STREQUAL "iOS")
  set ( bar_DIR "${BAR_INSTALLATION_PREFIX}/lib/bar" )
endif()
```

This sets the `<PackageName>_DIR` variable to the concrete folder where the package's config file (`bar-config.cmake`) is located. According to the [CMake docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) this can also be set as an environment variable.

It's not pretty, and it couples project "foo" to its dependency "bar" more than I would like, but as a workaround it will do for the moment.

I'm not marking this answer as "accepted" in case someone with more CMake knowledge comes up with a real solution.